# Author year citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have looking for how to cite the author and year in a sentence with reference to my bibliography list. I already used some Natbib styles, but no result of what I want.

This is my main file: thesis.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%Enabled packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %something with the header and footer
\usepackage{graphicx} %enables easy graphics embedding
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\include{Sections/Title}
\include{Sections/Abstract}
\tableofcontents
\include{Sections/chapterA}
\include{Sections/chapterB}
\include{Sections/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

My .bib file is called references.bib containing one example:

```
@book{hermanss2012,
author = "Astrid Hermanns",
title = "Psychology Management in Organizations",
publisher = "Cengage Learning EMEA",
year = "2012"
}
```

The place where I put the citation in the sentence is (as example) abstract.tex:

```
%Disable fancy page style
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent This is the place for the abstract\citeauthor{hermanns2012}
\end{abstract}
```

This is an image of the output of the pdf file

[image]

Instead of the "author?" I want the lastname of the author and the year as a citation there, like "This is the place for the abstract `(Hermanns, 2012)`"

Furtermore, I want that the books/reports/etc in the bibliography is sorted on alphabetical order, by starting with the lastname of the auther instead of a number.

Anyone suggestions of how to solve this issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include your biblography file as follows:

```
\bibliography{yourBibtexFile} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike} %or any other style you like
```

And then cite your reference using `\cite{hermanss2012}`

See the example below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is the place for the abstract\cite{hermanns2012}

\bibliography{test}           % Or whatever path and filename your bibtex is located
\bibliographystyle{apalike}   % Or any other style you like

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have entered your suggestion in the files, but there is a next issue. Because I can not answer my own question yet (reputation) this link will lead to the message I wanted to post after Dan his awnser: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6c1efb2fafc1f3fe999320334f37ea698443634b3

Comment: @drs.Ekingen you have to put `\bibliography{Sections/references}` since your `.bib` file is in `Sections` folder

Comment: @karlkoeller I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: The OP uses `natbib` with `number`. This must be changed to `authoryear`.

Comment: I changed `\usepackage[number]{natbib}` into `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` as Guido stated.

Comment: I changed `\usepackage[number]{natbib}` into `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` in the thesis.tex file as Guido stated. In the Abstract.tex file I have inserted the following lines: `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` and` \bibliography{bib/references}` because references.bib is in a bib folder. The error message can be found at [link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g8c71bc38b265b5cb99932054500fd3299de28e6c4)

Comment: I pasted the`\bibliographystyle etc`in the wrong .tex file. It must be pasted in bibliography.tex and works. In that case the path of karlkoeller was right, only `refrences` would be `bibliography`. I have another question: How to cite an author with name S.J. van den Burg? I want `(Van den Burg, 2010)` with the first letter as capital. In the list of references it must appear like `Burg, S.J. van den`. Is this possible? And, am I right that if you have`\citp{burg2010,appel2011}`that in both the list of references and text will apear Appel as first and then Burg due to the alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it worked for me. I wanted to be able to use citation inside the text for example using `\citet{Jones_2008}` for Jones et al., (2008) and `\citep{Jones_2008}` for (Jones et al 2000) and no numbers or brackets (brackets ex.[1] are the default for any style you use from the plain Latex bibliography system to natbib package). So be sure not to use `numbers` in `\usepackage[round, sort,numbers]{natbib}`. The `sort` option does the job of alphabetically sorting the bibliographies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle {plainnat}

\bibliography{pap}
\end{document}
```

Note: pap is the bibliography .bib file