# How to create a hyperlinked author-year citation?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the biblatex package, and I'd like to reproduce an effect similar to the one required in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121964/author-year-citation).

biblatex's standard \citeauthor{bibid} command puts in the authors name, but without a hyper link, or the year in which the article was written. I tried looking through the documentation for biblatex, but couldn't find a high level command at the level of autocite that would simply reproduce what I am looking for.

What are my options?

Comment: If you really use `biblatex`, its [`authoryear` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear.pdf) is the way to go. Of course, you would not cite with `\citeauthor{bibid}`, but with `\cite{bibid}`, `\parencite{bibid}` or `\textcite{bibid}`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be clearer if you stated directly what you want instead of referring to that other question. I may have misunderstood what you want but to cite author and year the normal commands are `\textcite` and `\parencite`. To get a link you need the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\textcite{westfahl:space}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```